# Simple VR has me stumped :( Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1

Tags: formula, validation

This is probably one of the basic questions I will ever ask, but at the moment I am stumped and cant work out how to do it

I need a validation rule to look at the  field “Canada_Email_Consent__c” if picklist value equals "Yes" then make field “Canada_Consent_Field__c” mandatory

Field API : Canada_Email_Consent__c
Data Type : Picklist
Values : Yes No

Field api :Canada_Consent_Field__c
Date Type : Picklist

This is my formula

```
IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c) = "Yes", 
        ISPICKVAL(Canada_Consent_Field__c)), True, False
 )
```

Looking forward to your response

Comment: `ISPICKVAL` expects two parameters. Try `IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c,"Yes"),
        ISPICKVAL(Canada_Consent_Field__c,"")), True, False
 )`

Comment: Thank you highfive. I have a feeling today is going to be a long day ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `ISPICKVAL()` is expecting two parameters but you are giving only one. Alter your formula to,

```
IF(
   AND(
     ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c,"Yes"),
     ISPICKVAL(Canada_Consent_Field__c,"")
   ),
 True, False  
)
```

For get more detail have look at [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISPICKVAL)